# Why the 1 year difference between Bar/Bat Mitzva?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, age, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

Why the difference of 1 year between girls reaching obligation in mitzva observation versus boys? (a girl's Bat Mitzva = 12 years old, while boy's Bar Mitzva = 13 years old)

Is this due to girl's reaching intellectual maturity faster in this area or perhaps some other reason.

Comment: I think there's an answer to this on this site. Haven't had a chance to find it, b/c I'm heading out to one of these events. I also think that your 2nd paragraph is the reason, as well.

Comment: Physical maturity seems more likely

Comment: @ray punishment is only at 20

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/29965/759

Comment: @DoubleAA good point.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8631 (cc @DanF)

Answer (score 2):

The Teshuvos Ha'Rosh (Klal 16-1) as well as other Rishonim point out that the age of Bar/Bas Mitzvah is a Halacha Li'Moshe Mi'Sinai and they imply that no ta'am was given. However since the concept of Bar/Base Mitzvah is intrinsically based on the concept of leaving the status of katnus  (which is compared to being a shoiteh by Chazal) and entering the stage of pikchus  (intellectual maturity) it would appear that in Hashem's eyes - at least with regards to understanding the concept of being responsible to do the will of Hashem and serve Him - girls do reach this stage of maturity earlier than boys.

Comment: do you have a source for that last statement?

Comment: @ray. No. I just figured it would be a logical deduction based on the the way Chazal understand the status of a katan. No source though.